# Moment.js get diferrent current time

Tags: momentjs

I want to get different two time :

```
var now = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
var then = moment().add('2', 'hours').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
console.log(now, then);
```

but, i got different `time` in second:

now = `2017-02-20 11:29:10`
then = `2017-02-20 11:29:20`

why?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this, but perhaps you paused for some reason (breakpoint, etc) between the first and second lines?  `moment()` gets the current time, which you did twice, but it's unlikely your code would freeze for 10 seconds between calls without intervention.

Comment: my code including in one function onclick.

Comment: And you can reproduce these results consistently?  Prove it.  Take a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

there is no way you will get difference in seconds except if you stop the execution of code by putting debug point or by executing some other code in between. even mili seconds will result the same as below.

```
var now = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss:sss");
var then = moment().add('2', 'hours').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss:sss');
console.log(now +" :: "+ then);
2017-03-06 21:38:16:1616 :: 2017-03-06 23:38:16:1616
```